# Adding a method to an attribute in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, metaprogramming

How do you define a method for an attribute of an instance in Ruby?

Let's say we've got a class called `HtmlSnippet`, which extends ActiveRecord::Base of Rails and has got an attribute `content`. And, I want to define a method `replace_url_to_anchor_tag!` for it and get it called in the following way;

```
html_snippet = HtmlSnippet.find(1)
html_snippet.content = "Link to http://stackoverflow.com"
html_snippet.content.replace_url_to_anchor_tag!
# => "Link to <a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>http://stackoverflow.com</a>"



# app/models/html_snippet.rb
class HtmlSnippet < ActiveRecord::Base    
  # I expected this bit to do what I want but not
  class << @content
    def replace_url_to_anchor_tag!
      matching = self.match(/(https?:\/\/[\S]+)/)
      "<a href='#{matching[0]}'/>#{matching[0]}</a>"
    end
  end
end
```

As `content` is an instance of String class, redefine String class is one option. But I don't feel like to going for it because it overwrites behaviour of all instances of String;

```
class HtmlSnippet < ActiveRecord::Base    
  class String
    def replace_url_to_anchor_tag!
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: oops, I always say thank you by comment but not by any operation in Stackoverflow. I will do it for this time

Comment: @oldergod could you give me a sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code is not working is simple - you are working with @content which is `nil` in the context of execution (the `self` is the class, not the instance). So you are basically modifying eigenclass of nil.

So you need to extend the instance of @content when it's set. There are few ways, there is one:

```
class HtmlSnippet < ActiveRecord::Base

  # getter is overrided to extend behaviour of freshly loaded values
  def content
    value = read_attribute(:content)
    decorate_it(value) unless value.respond_to?(:replace_url_to_anchor_tag)
    value
  end

  def content=(value)
    dup_value = value.dup
    decorate_it(dup_value)
    write_attribute(:content, dup_value)
  end

  private
  def decorate_it(value)
    class << value
      def replace_url_to_anchor_tag
        # ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

For the sake of simplicity I've ommited the "nil scenario" - you should handle `nil` values differently. But that's quite simple.

Another thing is that you might ask is why I use `dup` in the setter. If there is no `dup` in the code, the behaviour of the following code might be wrong (obviously it depends on your requirements):

```
x = "something"
s = HtmlSnippet.find(1)
s.content = x

s.content.replace_url_to_anchor_tag # that's ok
x.content.replace_url_to_anchor_tag # that's not ok
```

Wihtout `dup` you are extending not only x.content but also original string that you've assigned.

Comment: Wow, this is gorgeous! I see how I can access an instance attribute in a class.